# SWRL:not expecting an unbound argument for (0-offset) argument #1

Tags: ontology, semantic-web, protege, swrl

I'm trying to run this code on sqwrl tab in protege 5.5.0,but there is an error:

```
swrlb:date("2010-10-10Z"^^xsd:date, ?a, ?b, ?c, ?d) -> sqwrl:select(?a)
```

error:

```
    Exception running SQWRL query S5: error running SQWRL queries: error transferring rules to Drools rule engine:
[Error: invoker.invoke("S5", "swrlb:date", 0, false, new VPATH(), new BAVNs("", "a", "b", "c", "d"), new L("2010-10-10Z", "xsd:date"), new UBA("a"), new UBA("b"), new UBA("c"), new UBA("d")): built-in exception thrown by built-in swrlb:date in rule S5: exception thrown by built-in swrlb:date in rule S5: not expecting an unbound argument for (0-offset) argument #1]
[Near : {... invoker.invoke("S5", "swrlb:da ....}]
             ^
[Line: 1, Column: 1]: error transferring rules to Drools rule engine:
[Error: invoker.invoke("S5", "swrlb:date", 0, false, new VPATH(), new BAVNs("", "a", "b", "c", "d"), new L("2010-10-10Z", "xsd:date"), new UBA("a"), new UBA("b"), new UBA("c"), new UBA("d")): built-in exception thrown by built-in swrlb:date in rule S5: exception thrown by built-in swrlb:date in rule S5: not expecting an unbound argument for (0-offset) argument #1]
[Near : {... invoker.invoke("S5", "swrlb:da ....}]
             ^
[Line: 1, Column: 1]: [Error: invoker.invoke("S5", "swrlb:date", 0, false, new VPATH(), new BAVNs("", "a", "b", "c", "d"), new L("2010-10-10Z", "xsd:date"), new UBA("a"), new UBA("b"), new UBA("c"), new UBA("d")): built-in exception thrown by built-in swrlb:date in rule S5: exception thrown by built-in swrlb:date in rule S5: not expecting an unbound argument for (0-offset) argument #1]
[Near : {... invoker.invoke("S5", "swrlb:da ....}]
             ^
[Line: 1, Column: 1]: built-in exception thrown by built-in swrlb:date in rule S5: exception thrown by built-in swrlb:date in rule S5: not expecting an unbound argument for (0-offset) argument #1: exception thrown by built-in swrlb:date in rule S5: not expecting an unbound argument for (0-offset) argument #1: not expecting an unbound argument for (0-offset) argument #1
```

Comment: Missing timezone, I guess.

Comment: @StanislavKralin but timezone is there in the expression! it is declared by `Z` sign